# JQuery method .before() or .insertBefore() on IE7

Tags: jquery, css, checkbox, internet-explorer-7

I am trying to insert a color div before a checkbox, using `.before()` method of jQuery 1.5.1, which runs alright on FF, Chrome, IE8+; but for IE7, the inserted color div is not at the same line as checkbox. I wish somebody could give me any advice. thanks. codes attached:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="checkbox" id="check1" />PINK
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var colorHtml = '<div style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); display: inline-block;   margin-left: 20px; width: 12px;"><div style="width: 4px; height: 0pt; border: 4px solid rgb(200,100,200); overflow: hidden;"></div></div>';
        $("#check1").before(colorHtml);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

screen shot:

IE7:
[image: IE7]

IE8: [image: IE8]

**UPDATED:**

adding float:left:[image]

not using float, adding "zoom:1; *display:inline;": [image]

Answer (score 3):

You can get them on the same line by adding `float:left;` to the style of your colorHtml outer div:

```
<div style="float: left; border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); display: inline-block;   margin-left: 20px; width: 12px;"><div style="width: 4px; height: 0pt; border: 4px solid rgb(200,100,200); overflow: hidden;"></div></div>
```

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G4sY4/2/

Comment: it works, but not perfectly. do you know how to make them in the exact same line? as you see, the color div is still a little higher than the checkbox.. thanks for your help!

Comment: When I want things to line up on a line I normally add a container element and set its line-height.

Answer (score 1):

change display: inline-block to inline, that should fix the issue. block display type causes a line break after the tag

Comment: sorry, meant to say set to inline.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the `inline-block` style setting.  IE7 doesn't really do it right.  Try floating it left within the container and not setting `inline-block`.

**Update**: You can find a description of the problem and an alternative work around at: http://flipc.blogspot.com/2009/02/damn-ie7-and-inline-block.html

Summary: Add "zoom:1; *display: inline;"